# How do I find all documents in a collection that match a pair of fields in another collection?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

We have some collections that we need to lookup across and return all matching documents from a collection. There's a users table, a daily metrics table, and a userspaces table (which tracks which user falls in which organization).
The goal is to fetch all metrics documents for users that belong to an organization, with some user details. I'm not sure if I'm using the right stages/accumulators, for forgetting to unwind at the right stage.

Sample documents:
daily_metrics:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "640a7f519b12b8a960362e33"
  },
  "user": {
    "$oid": "6408109bac3a6db93dcbe03d"
  },
  "metrics": {
    "steps": 6911,
    "calories": 463.63,
    "distance": 3870.62
  },
  "localDate": "03-10-2023",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1678409553242"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1678512627838"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

userspaces:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "620158cc4b23c40d3457c0c1"
  },
  "organization": {
    "$oid": "6200f8aa4b23c40d3457c0a9"
  },
  "user": {
    "$oid": "61f0fd1eb3dea2d99c6f9658"
  },
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1644255436192"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1644255436192"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0
}
```

users:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "61ee66c227b40d7b5fc912e4"
  },
  "verified": true,
  "name": "Amanchira",
  "email": "amanchirasdf96@gmail.com",
  "profile_image": "https://d25ji.cloudfront.net/profileimages/asfsefkze.jpg",
  "createdAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1643013826921"
    }
  },
  "updatedAt": {
    "$date": {
      "$numberLong": "1659381101772"
    }
  },
  "__v": 0,
  "profile_id": "amanchira1"
}
```

Expected output document, for one organization, for every user and  localDate pair:

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "640835b4ac3a6db93dcbe187"
  },
  "name": [
    "Adeanlika"
  ],
  "dp": [],
  "handle": [
    "adeanlika"
  ],
  "date": "03-10-2023",
  "steps": 17635.25,
  "distance": 13819,
  "calories": 692.4
}
```

My aggregation pipeline, on daily metrics, looks like this for now:

```
[
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "userspaces",
      localField: "user",
      foreignField: "user",
      as: "userspaces",
    },
  },
  {
    $lookup: {
      from: "users",
      localField: "user",
      foreignField: "_id",
      as: "userdetails",
    },
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$userspaces",
  },
  {
    $match: {
      createdAt: {
        $gte: ISODate("2023-03-09T18:30:00.000Z"),
        $lt: ISODate("2023-03-30T18:30:00.000Z"),
      },
      "userspaces.organization": ObjectId(
        "63fdb56aac3a6db93dcbbc22"
      ),
    },
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$user",
      name: {
        $first: "$userdetails.name",
      },
      dp: {
        $first: "$userdetails.profile_image",
      },
      handle: {
        $first: "$userdetails.profile_id",
      },
      date: {
        $first: "$localDate",
      },
      steps: {
        $sum: "$metrics.steps",
      },
      distance: {
        $sum: "$metrics.distance",
      },
      calories: {
        $sum: "$metrics.calories",
      },
    },
  },
  {
    $sort: {
      name: 1,
    },
  },
]
```

This is of course, aggregating all daily metrics data into one document per user, with the first localDate.
We need separate documents per user, per localDate to be returned, for users that have a matching document in the given organization.

Comment: Please provide sample input data and desired result.

Comment: @kaishuvam7 nothing wrong with your query. but if your actual data same with your post, the problem was in the user ID and company didnt match. you can test your query in https://mongoplayground.net/p/a69ocKi-TDH,  i only fixed the user ID

Comment: @TobokSitanggang the problem is that I need all localDates' docs for each user. Not just one with all of it aggregated. So if the organization has 3 users and they have 5 daily_metrics docs each, I should output 15 docs - one for each user and localDate pair.